# Is there a way to read a text file from resources without typing the file name?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("xyz.project.Folder1.Folder2.SomeFile.Txt"))
{
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(stream);
    string fileContents = tr.ReadToEnd();
}

var html = File.ReadAllText(Properties.Resources.FilesTypes);
var html = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\New folder (44)\New Text Document.txt");
```

In the original and what is working i used the lastl ine:

```
var html = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\New folder (44)\New Text Document.txt");
```

But then i added the text file to my project resources since i want the file to be in the program all the time and not to read it from the hard disk.

Then i added the code with the assembly

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("xyz.project.Folder1.Folder2.SomeFile.Txt"))
{
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(stream);
    string fileContents = tr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

But in this case i need to type the name of the file manualy.
So i tried this line:

```
var html = File.ReadAllText(Properties.Resources.FilesTypes);
```

But getting exception:

> Illegal characters in path

Comment: You need to set the file name instead of passing in filetypes... See your resources resx file and find your text resource name and add it instead of filetypes... This is pretty obvious ... Read the method summaries  maybe ?

Comment: Just string html = Properties.Resources.FilesTypes; is working. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a typo in your post, how is this even compiling? In your first code snippet there are two `var html = ` initializations. You say that `File.ReadAllText(Properties.Resources.FilesTypes)` works, but then you set the same variable to `File.ReadAllText(@"E:\New folder (44)\New Text Document.txt");` straight after